# MSVS 2019 publishes angular asp.net mvc core site with random JS file names

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio

I develop asp.net mvc .net core 3.1 web application that is configured to use angular with "default" settings.
I publish regulary my project (right mouse click on project -> publish) to a local folder and every time I'm dissapointed by js filenames provided by build. They are random:

main-es2015.4fb3e45d9b23af7613d6
main-es2015.41c3454ba4099a49058f
...

How can I stabilize build and have constant file names from build to build?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I replaced "outputHashing":"all" to "none" in agular.json